# Increase Varchar in a SQL Server 2005 column and connected erp

Tags: sql-server-2005, varchar, erp

I don't know if you can help me in this problem. I have an ERP connected to a SQL Server 2005 database. I need to increase the characters permitted in the description of my articles... If I increase the column to `varchar(80)` that I have in the description column is it enough? Can increasing it damage my database or my software?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the size in the database in your example shouldn't be the problem. The problem, if there is one, would be from your ERP application. I have worked with some where they assume the table/field sizes are fixed and not changeable so that application would fail on the size change. Other ERP systems do not care about the size change and will continue to work... but... the system tables during upgrades could rebuild the table to the install/upgrade size which might change your data size for your column back to its original size. Also there could be a mask in your application limiting the user from entering in a value larger than what the field would except in your table. All things to consider but you will never know until you test these to know for sure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try on a test environment changing the lenght in the db.. Instead, do you know where I can search in the erp, where to change the form limit if it can be? Even if I've local installation on each client, so this would mean to change it in every client... is right? This change, if made on the client, may damage the db? Or the DB will simple trunkate excess character?

Comment: It really depend on the application you are using and if the size is something you can configure thought settings in your application.